# Formula returns values slightly below "correct" answer?

Tags: javascript, formula

Okay, I'm far from a math whiz. Heck, the fact that I remembered enough high school algebra to cobble together any working formula is a triumph for me. So if you notice an unecessarily long or confusing formula here, that explains that.

But, as one could reasonably expect, something has gone wrong here.

I'm trying to make a simple calculator that displays the cost savings of buying trip tickets for transit versus paying a cash fare. I'm pretty close, but the calculations from the formulas I'm using are not working right in some cases and I can't figure out why.

In the example below, the Base zone and zone 4 calculate the difference as I expected, while zones 1-3 return answers just a teensy bit below the correct answer (i.e. $105.60000000000014 instead of $106), and Zones 1 and 2 return the same answer though the formula is different.

I've looked at this till I've gone crosseyed. I'm sure the answer is pretty plain, but I can't see it. Anybody?

Thanks for the help.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="javascript">

<!-- Begin Trip Tickets Savings Calc script
function  doMath4() {
    var one = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[0].value);
    var two = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[1].value);
    var selection = document.getElementsByName("zonett")[0].value;

    if(selection == "z4"){
        var prodZ4tt = (((one  *   two) * 4.25) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ4tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z3"){
        var prodZ3tt = (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.35) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ3tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z2"){
        var prodZ2tt = (((one  *   two) * 3) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 2.8) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ2tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z1"){
        var prodZ1tt = (((one  *   two) * 2.5) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 2.3) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ1tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "Base"){
        var prodBasett = (((one  *   two) * 1.5) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 1.5) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodBasett  +  ".");
    }
}

// End Trip Tickets Savings Calc script -->

</script>
</head>

<body>


<form name="theForm4" class="calcform">
<h2>You Do the Math: Commuter Express Trip Tickets Vs. Cash</h2>
<div class="calcform-content">
    <div class="formrow-calc">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Days you commute on Commuter Express monthly:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="formrow-calc">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Daily boardings on Commuter Express Bus:</p>

        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fareexampletable">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="savingsleft"><p class="ifyouride">EXAMPLE:</p></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Go to work:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="savingsright"><p>1 time</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Come home from work:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="additionline savingsright"><p>+1 time</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Total:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="savingsright"><p>2 times</p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="formrow-calc savings-zone">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Choose Zone:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <select name="zonett">
          <option value="Base">Base</option>
          <option value="z1">Zone 1</option>
          <option value="z2">Zone 2</option>
          <option value="z3">Zone 3</option>
          <option value="z4">Zone 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="formrow-calc">


          <div class="calcform-col4-ce">


 <button type="submit" onclick="doMath4()" class="btn-submit"><div class="btn-submit"><img src="img/btn_savings.png" alt="Show My Yearly Savings" /></div></button> 


    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">


</div>



</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree @hammar although a bit more insight could have been shown to the user.. try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Comment: Thanks, gruntled. Indeed, more insight is helpful, I'm afraid the answer you linked to is complete greek to me. Epsilon value? Error constant? Fact is, I'm a designer and front end guy, but inevitably guys like me are called upon to make stuff like this work, even though guys like me limped through Intro to Counting in college. So I guess I'm asking how this applies to my situation and how I can get this to work for me...?

Comment: Basically, because computers calculate numbers in base 2 (1 and 0), some numbers are impossible to get exact. Instead, they will be off by 0.00000001 or some such number. Call [Math.Round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) on your result to get it to a "close enough" state, or you may need to write your own rounding function if integers don't have enough precision.

Comment: Thanks Michal! That makes as much sense as anything - We went over binary language in college math, when they taught me that 3 = 011. I dropped the class shortly there after and now I draw pretty pictures all day. Any hints on how best to achieve this, syntax wise?

Comment: @user719431 From Michals comment all you need to do is call Math.Round() on your variable. It doesn't really matter if you don't understand why it doesn't work perfectly. Check out: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

Comment: @user719431 Also most of your brackets aren't needed. multiplkication always goes from left to right. so `(((one * two) *3)*12)` is the same as `(one * two * 3 * 12)` It won't change anything but it might make it easier to read. No big deal though it might be good to have a quick read up on order of operations.

Comment: Appreciate it, &James Khoury! I actually found that link trying to figure this out for myself. I tried calling it on a variable, but my syntax must be wrong:

Comment: '    else if(selection == "z3"){
        var prodZ3tt = (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.35) *12);
  Math.round(prodZ3tt*100)/100;
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ3tt  +  ".");
    }'

Comment: You can actually remove one * two * 12 from every instance, doing that equation early and using the result instead.  That's because you're doing that equation everywhere.  Also, the bottom equation (Base) always equals zero.

Comment: @staticbeast, Thanks! I'll definitely refine the codes and formulas as soon as I get it working (I've got about 20 minutes to come up with a solution. :/ Right now I just wish I could get that rounding call to work.

Comment: @Michal - "Basically, because computers calculate numbers in base 2 (1 and 0), some numbers are impossible to get exact."  Um...no they're not. There are plenty of programming languages that provide native language support for exact maths (and I for one don't really care how they achieve this under the hood). Unfortunately JavaScript is not one of them, which in my opinion was a stupid decision on the part of its designers, especially given that its use on web pages has inevitably resulted in lots of JavaScript code being written by people who haven't studied programming or maths.

Comment: @nnnnnn Amen to that last. However, I still am without a solution. So am I to understand that this question is simply too stupid to get a clear answer? Is stackoverflow meant only for those who have studied programming or math(s)? Comic-Book-Guy-Like responses like "Floating. Point. Math." are honestly only slightly less helpful than referring someone to a 75 page PDF on Epsilon constants. By all means, have fun at my expense, but when you're done, answer the question and get some points. Isn't that the idea of this site? I mean, here's the code I'm using, what needs to change to make it work?

Comment: @user719431 I can't do anything at the moment, but I will check back at the weekend and put an actual answer with code for you (if one hasn't appeared by then).

Comment: @user719431 - I didn't mean to imply that your question was stupid, I was commenting only on what Michal had said in his comment. To actually answer your question, I rarely need to do floating point maths in JavaScript but I think the last time I did I ended up multiplying all of the numbers involved by some factor big enough to remove the decimals before doing my calculation, and then dividing the final answer by the same amount. Or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken/3644354#3644354 for a tidy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code cleaned up as I discussed in my comment:

```
function  doMath4() {
    var one = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[0].value);
    var two = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[1].value);
    var selection = document.getElementsByName("zonett")[0].value;

    var m12 = one * two * 12;
    var prod = null;

    if(selection == "z4")
    {
        prod = (m12 * 4.25)  - (m12 * 3.75);
    }
    else if(selection == "z3")
    {
        prod = (m12 * 3.75) - (m12 * 3.35);
    }
    else if(selection == "z2")
    {
        prod = (m12 * 3) - (m12 * 2.8);
    }
    else if(selection == "z1")
    {
        prod = (m12 * 2.5) - (m12 * 2.32);
    }
    else if(selection == "Base")
    {
        prod = (m12 * 1.5) - (m12 * 1.5); //This is always 0?
    }

    if(prod != null)
    {
            prod = Math.round(prod);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prod  +  ".");
    }
}
```

The simplest solution to your question is included above (and below):

```
prod = Math.round(prod);
```

This will round the result (prod) to the nearest whole number, regardless of what it is. So in your example, $105.600000... would be rounded up to $106, which is what you asked for.